# Buttons in NSTableView to open file

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I have an `NStableView` that is populated with an `NSMutableArray` that is built from a `SQL` data base... all good.

One cell displays a path to a locally stored `pdf`. I'd like to have that cell or text open up the `pdf` with `Preview` when clicked.  The cell can be a button or just text- that's not really important (I'll do whatever is easiest) so long as it opens up `Preview` with the `pdf`.  I know I can implement the following to call `Preview`

```
[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] openFile:theUrl withApplication:@"Preview"];
```

The part I'm not sure of is how to make a cell call that action... That is, how do I turn a cell into a button where the contents of the cell (the path) is passed to the action as "theUrl"

Thanks in advance...

Comment: In a cell based table view there is a button cell but I recommend to use a view based table view, then you can use a simple `IBAction` and get the row with `rowForView`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Create a subclass of NSTableCellView and add the following:**

In your interface:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSURL *url;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet NSButton *urlButton;
```

In your implementation:

```
- (void)setURL:(NSURL *)url {
   _url = url;
   _urlButton.title = url.absoluteString ?: @"Missing url";
}

- (IBAction)didPressURLButton {
    [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] openFile:_url withApplication:@"Preview"];
}
```

**In your storyboard/nib:**

1. Design your NSTableView and NSTableCellView
2. Assign the above subclass to NSTableCellView and don't forget to set its identifier to something unique and connect its IBOutlet and IBAction

**In your NSTableViewDataSource/Delegate:**

1. Create a table cell with makeViewWithIdentifer: and pass in the identifier you assigned above.
2. Call setURL: on your tablecell for that row

This is more thorough than required, but once you know how to do it this way, you should be able to add and expand it to whatever other functionality you want to add.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you for walking through it step by step- I appreciate it and hope that it;s helpful to others who come looking!